# What's the raku analog of perl 5's carp?

Tags: exception, raku, die, carp

By default, Raku's "die" reports the line number where the "die" is located, what if you'd like the line number of the calling context, ala "carp" with perl 5?

Comment: FWIW I'm working on a module now.  Will post again once I'm done.

Answer (score 10):

There is no direct equivalent to `carp`, but you *can* start raku with the `--ll-exception` parameter, which will create a **full** stack trace on an execution error.

I guess nobody has gotten around to creating a `Carp` module yet.  Creating a `carp` sub shouldn't be too difficult, given that there is a [`Backtrace`](https://docs.raku.org/type/Backtrace) class:

```
$ raku -e 'say "file: {.file}:{.line}" for Backtrace.new' 
file: SETTING::src/core.c/Backtrace.pm6:94
file: SETTING::src/core.c/Backtrace.pm6:94
file: -e:1
```

Answer (score 3):

There is now a [Carp module](https://github.com/alabamenhu/Carp) available on GitHub and should soon be available in the Raku ecosystem. It currently only supports the most basic functionality, but over time it should be improved.

So the answer to your question is to use Carp like you would in Perl 5. :-)